# Using openpyxl to do numerous computations on large set of data

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am interested in using openpyxl to gather key metrics about a large data set I have. Two things I am interested in are *cardinality*, and *field importance* (i.e. how many "null" or "junk" values do we have for this field). I am running into performance problems and was wondering if there was any way my code could be optimized. My largest excel file has ~20,000 rows. I am aware of optimized reader for openpyxl, but I need to look at every cell and get its value.

My script is reading data from a large xlsx file and writing to a google doc that houses information about each field.

```
def run(table, limit_percent_null):

    excel_workbook = load_workbook(filename = settings.mypath + table + '.xlsx', read_only=True)
    excel_sheet = excel_workbook.worksheets[0]

    d = dict()
    # first loop through our fields

    for i in range(1, excel_sheet.get_highest_column()):
        key = excel_sheet.cell(row = 1, column = i).value
        if key is None:
            break;

        # key is the field and value is list of booleans 
        # true = null or empty, false = has an actual value
        d[key] = []

        # low loop through actual values of those fields
        for j in range(2, excel_sheet.get_highest_row()):
            field = excel_sheet.cell(row = j, column = i).value

            # does the field have "null" in it or is empty?
            if field is None:
                d[key].append(True)
            else:
                d[key].append(True if "null" in str(field) else False)

    # write to google doc
    google_sheet = settings.open_gspread_connetion(table)
    for key, value in d.items():
        # omitted
```

Comment: What performance problems are you encountering? 20,000 rows isn't that much. BTW. there is little point in trying to beat `ws.iter_rows()` for going through the data. `ws.columns` should be available but I think your code should be rewritten solely to work with rows to avoid nested loops.